# How can I host my Springboot application in my own computer like a background service?

Tags: java, spring, service, hosting

I want to host my springboot application on my on PC, I want it to start with the computer, just like databases do. But I can't find anything related (probably because I am asking the 'wrong' way). **There is any way to start the springboot application with my pc in the background, with no CMD showing or having to keep intelijj open?**

I tried to search how to host the application, but didn't found any thing 'locally' based, everything was how to host in X cloud or Y domain/host. What I want is to my application run on the background of my PC so I can use it as a personal system, but don't want to keep a cmd open or intelijj

Also I can't really use docker.. that was the way I was trying before, but I can't let Hyper-v active..

Comment: You should take a look at: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: What operation system do you have? What you need is create service. You can google how to do it for your specific OS, it is platform dependent.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answer! I use win 10, as I said above, sadly I can't use docker because of the hyper-v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 steps:

1. Get command line of execution of your application runned by IntelliJ. To do so:
   [image]
2. You have to create a file with extension ".bat" (batch file) with the contents of the command copied above, than  follow the steps bellow to define it to run in the startup configuration of the windows 10:
   Run a batch file at loading of Windows 8 and 10 Once the shortcut is created, right-click the shortcut file and select Cut. Press Start, type Run, and press Enter . In the Run window, type shell:startup to open the Startup folder.